# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '() => boolean'. in angular types script file

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Trying to make the checked value to false. But is is throwing error:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '() => boolean'.

in Angular typesscript file

```
export class InboxComponent implements AfterViewInit {

@ViewChildren('NotRes')

  NotRes: QueryList<Checkbox>;


  private disableNotResponsible(rowIndex: number): void {

    this. NotRes.toArray()[rowIndex].checked = false;

  }

}
```

getting above error at "**this. NotRes.toArray()[rowIndex].checked = false;**". While assigning or making checked to false the

Comment: Sounds like you're assigning a `boolean` value (`false`) to a function definition.

Comment: It seems like the `checked` property is a read-only function and not something that can be set directly. I'm not familiar with the QueryList or Checkbox behavior but there might be a separate `setChecked` method that needs to be called instead.